# How To Develop LBS app for Android

Tags: android, gis

I want to develop a LBS app for Android,but I do not know how to begin the project.

I want to use the Google Map API to use the map data of Google.The user can also add information on map,and the information can show on the map.
(For example,an user find one street is not safe,then the street will be red on the map.)

And I use the MSSQL SERVER or Oracle to store the information,but I don`t know how to get and use the data when I need it,should I use a GIS Engine(like ArcGIS)?
How can I show the information on Google Map?And Which GIS Engine I should use?
I also have another idea to use the Google Maps Data API.

Anybody can give me some suggestions?Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions could be following:

1. You can use MSSQL Server 2008 or Oracle to store data. [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) is even better because it's free and has a solid spatial capabilities.
2. As GIS engine you could use [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org). It works with all databases mentioned above. From my own experience it works really good with PostGIS.
3. If you want a native Android app you can go ahead and use native Google Maps APIs and manually construct WFS requests in order to communicate with Geoserver when storing data in the database. 
   Another option is to built it as a webpage and use coming [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) 2.11 javascript library which has great support for mobile devices. It's also great at constructing WFS requests so you won't need to handle this stuff manually. If you still want an Android map, you can use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com) to wrap you OpenLayers webpage into an app.